# Docker Webapp doesn't show up

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, docker

I'm new to Docker and trying to setup a container that runs a simple Tomcat J2EE web application. I have built a Docker file with the following contents:

```
from tomcat
MAINTAINER Mike Storey (mike@ssgpp.com)
RUN rm -rf /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT
ADD ./ROOT.war //usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
EXPOSE 80 8080
```

And after building and starting the container I can see the docker process running

```
docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                         COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
18518f75ca81        flatballflyer/aetkidmu:v1.7   "catalina.sh run"   7 minutes ago       Up 7 minutes        0.0.0.0:32770->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32769->8080/tcp   backstabbing_snyder
```

I see that port 8080 in the docker container is mapped to 0.0.0.0:32769 but when I visit that address on my host I get a failed to connect error. When I log into the container using

```
docker exec -it backstabbing_snyder  bash
```

and then do a

```
curl localhost:8080
```

I get the expected html page. Not sure what I'm missing here, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Resorted to Stackoverflow too quickly, the answer is that the 0.0.0.0 IP is not "real", and you should use the IP from the "docker-machine ip default" command with the port provided by the "docker ps" command. It seems to me that this is a common enough task that there would be an easier way to find the full URI.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, the command docker ps which shows you the mapping for [0.0.0.0:port] is only telling you that the host is ready to listen to that assigned port and then maps you to the mapped port which is your container's exposed.

So as per your comment, have you resolved it?

Comment: Yes, resolved. My resolution was 3 steps. Step1- execute `docker-machine ip default` to get the docker ip address. Step 2- execute `docker ps` to identify the port-mappings. Step3 print link to to host:port/[page] for docker user to see jumping-off point. I subsequently changed my Docker Run commands to map to specific ports allowing me to side-step Step 2 above.